# firestore Check if id exists against an array of ids

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I developing a simple chat applicaiton for my website using firebase firestore. where every chat session has an id

provided i have an array of ids

`chat_sessions = ["q93XhadA9QQLu6X8yfZB", "YXEYISEI8b2iixCcP3VO", "GXrSZbtrmN5NcrtvjFYp"]`

I want to get all document whose id is equal to any of the id's in the chat_sessions object using the code below.

```
return this.afs
    .collection('chats', ref => ref.where('uid','in_array',chat_sessions)).snapshotChanges...
```

but I am not getting any results.

I come from a PHP/MYSQL background
the PHP equivalent of what i am trying to achieve will be sth like this in PHP

```
if(in_array(uid,chat_sessions)){
      get(doc/uid)
      }
```

can anyone help with the right query where  we check for document id against a list of ids in an array? Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found something else on firestore i.e `"array-contains-any"` for this case.

Maybe it's updated now.

[image: Firestore condition]

Comment: array_contains_any is was added to recent firestore updates. This was not available at the time of asking the question but will accept it as the answer because it works now. Thanks Kumar

Answer (score 10):

Thank you @frank van Puffelen. You were almost right. I should have used `in` instead of `in_array`

```
ref.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),'in_array',chat_sessions)
```

did not work. Instead I replaced `in_array` with `in` :

```
ref.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),'in',chat_sessions)
```

This worked! Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Your query is:

```
ref.where('uid','in_array',chat_sessions)
```

This checks a field called `uid` in each document against the values of the `chat_sessions`.

It seems that instead you want to the check the ID of each document against the array, which you can do with:

```
ref.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),'in_array',chat_sessions)
```

Comment: What is the equivalent in v9 to test against document id? firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.fieldpath doesn't seem to be the right choice...

Comment: Found it: `import {documentId} from "firebase/firestore"; ...where(documentId(), 'in', chat_sessions)`https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#documentid

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Hi, firebase did some update recently, so for do it I found out this method

`

```
const [products, setProduct] = useState([]);
const ids = ['H11LlJsh3sObwORZhA0b','om9m0lU9HYWyOJZKvEdi','1AoHyHuSFcF01zoyXyTD','6xoBlxsRXUoyzBUcWl0F',
'GJqthlmBGZaFAJqtC2jK','QNT3PxMfhNGg1RZnuqcq','RZgGoFZHyDAYaVZJWxGk','g4UO5P0EgtEqJnawwhXX','gyrZm8p0cEgJdDvTuB1g','mrscldfeYlkaSF151MpI',]

useEffect(() => {
    const saveFirebaseTodos = [];      
    ids.forEach((element) => {
    fetchMyAPI()
    async function fetchMyAPI() {
        const q = query(collection(db, "a"), where('__name__', '==', element));
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q); 
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        saveFirebaseTodos.push(({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}));
        /*console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());*/
        if (ids.length == saveFirebaseTodos.length) {
            setProduct(saveFirebaseTodos) 
            }
        });
    }})

}, [])`
```

In this way, you can check how many element in arrays you want (bypassing 10 elements limit of firebase).

Hope can help anyone :D

Answer (score 0):

It's 2023 and today you can simply do:

```
import { doc, documentId, onSnapshot, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore'

const partnerCandidatesQuery = query(
  usersCollection,
  where('role', '==', 'candidate'),
  where(
    documentId(),
    'in',
    candidateIds.map((id) => doc(usersCollection, id)),
  ),
)
```