# Find documents in which a certain id inside an array exists in firestore (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Im trying to check if the current user id is in the participants array.How do i do it in firestore.Tried using 'array-contains'>please check the image

Comment: Are you looking for [How to use array-contains operator with an array of objects in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188508/how-to-use-array-contains-operator-with-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore/68188623#68188623) ?

Comment: Tried this    db.collection("ChatRooms").where("participants", "array-contains", userObj)  ....How do i get the actual data

Comment: You need to pass the complete object i.e. `{email: "theEmail", objId: "theObjId", userName: "theUsername"}` I'd recommend storing the users' UIDs only in that array then you can use the array-contains easily. Then fetch the email and other info in a separate query.

Comment: @johnoula If you tried something but had trouble making it work, edit your question to show the [complete, minimal/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that, it'll be hard to help beyond linking you to documentation or to previous questions where folks *do* show what they tried.

Comment: @Dharmaraj tried it already.

Comment: @johnoula did you try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524946/firestore-check-if-id-exists-against-an-array-of-ids), Could you please share more information like what are all the steps you have tried so far and elaborate what your looking for ?